Text Wrap in HTML
I have an example below about my problem:
Paragraphs do not behave the same when the line break is automatic (like with flex width) or when it is forced.
I need that when the line break in the paragraph is automatic, the size of the paragraph inside of the div behave just like when the line break is forced (so the div size also changes to the size of the broken paragraph).
That's the code I used:
CSS:
body {
    display: flex;
}

.myDiv {
    border: 0;
    height: 70px;
    background: #ededed;
    border-left: 1px solid #8e8e8e;
    padding: 0;
}

.myDiv:last-child {
    border-right: 1px solid #8e8e8e;
}

p {
    background: #ffffff;
}


HTML:
<div class="myDiv"><p>Planeta Terra</p></div>
<div class="myDiv"><p>Planeta Terra</p></div>
<div class="myDiv"><p>Planeta Terra</p></div>
<div class="myDiv"><p>Planeta Terra</p></div>
<div class="myDiv"><p>Planeta Terra</p></div>
<div class="myDiv"><p>Planeta<br>Terra</p></div>
<div class="myDiv"><p>Planeta Terra</p></div>
<div class="myDiv"><p>Planeta Terra</p></div>
<div class="myDiv"><p>Planeta Terra</p></div>
<div class="myDiv"><p>Planeta Terra</p></div>
<div class="myDiv"><p>Planeta Terra</p></div>

Green line has forced break, blue line don't
I've tried already using the text-wrap, word-break, white-space properties and others, but all of them behave just like the automatic break and the code doesn't recognize as a forced line break.
